# dash code error: TypeError: Unexpected keyword argument `selected_columns`

Tags: python, plotly-dash

> Using **Dash Data Table**, getting the above exception when running the app.

Comment: Would you mind to add these sections to your question: "Include details about your goal

", "Describe expected and actual results", "Descibe what you've tried" and "Show some code".

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by upgrading to the latest version of Dash (pip install dash --upgrade)